# Maximizing the logarithm of the determinant plus the trace of the inverse of a matrix

Tags: matrices, optimization, matrix-calculus

How can I solve the following unconstrained optimization problem in $\alpha \in \mathbb R$?

$$\text{maximize} \quad \log \det( \alpha A+I) + \mbox{tr} \left((\alpha A + I)^{-1} \alpha A \right)$$

where $A$ is a positive semidefinite matrix and $I$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: What is meant by the division? matrix inverse? or element-wise division?

Comment: Matrix inverse. Thanks. @whyyes

Comment: Got it. Just off the bat, everything here seems to be do-able using just the eigenvalues of $A$. So, if $A = V\Lambda V^T$, then $\log |\alpha A+ I| = \sum_i \log(\alpha \lambda_i + 1)$ and $tr((\alpha A+I)^{-1}(\alpha A) = tr((\alpha \Lambda+I)^{-1}(\alpha \Lambda) = \sum_i \frac{\alpha \lambda_i}{\alpha \lambda_i + 1}$. That reduces things to scalars / vectors. However the remaining function still seems nonconvex and I can't think of a closed-form solution off the top of my head; some reformulation may be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a new matrix variable $$X=I+\alpha A$$
and note the following relationships
$$\eqalign{
\alpha A &= X-I \cr
\alpha AX^{-1} &= (X-I)X^{-1} = I-X^{-1} \cr
 dX &= A\,d\alpha \cr
}$$
Now write the objective function in terms of $X$
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \log\det X + {\rm tr}(\alpha AX^{-1}) \cr
   &= \log\det X + {\rm tr}(I) - {\rm tr}(X^{-1}) \cr
}$$ The function is unbounded as $\alpha\to\infty\,\,$ since the trace term tend to zero while the log-det term increases.

Now find the differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
df &= d{\rm tr}(\log X-X^{-1}) \cr
  &= {\rm tr}((X^{-1}-X^{-2})\,dX) \cr
  &= {\rm tr}((X^{-1}-X^{-2})A)\,d\alpha \cr
  &= {\rm tr}(\alpha A^2X^{-2})\,d\alpha \cr\cr
\frac{df}{d\alpha}&= \alpha\,{\rm tr}(A^2X^{-2}) \cr
}$$
Setting the gradient to zero, means either
$\alpha=0$ or the trace-term is zero.

Since 
$$\lim_{|\alpha|\to\infty} AX^{-1} = \lim_{|\alpha|\to\infty} I\alpha^{-1} = 0$$ one way to drive the trace-term to zero is to let $\alpha$ take on very large values.

It might be possible to find other real values for $\alpha$ which annihilate the trace, but those would depend on the properties of each specific $A$ matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want $\alpha$ to be non-negative?  It looks like your objective function is concave.  If so, the minimum is achieved at the extreme points of the allowed range for $\alpha$.  That is, at $\alpha=0$ or $\alpha=\infty$.  Obviously $\alpha=\infty$ isn't it, so the answer is $\alpha=0.$

As a Rodrigo de Azevedo  points out, the maximum is not attained.  If your matrix has eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, the  objective function is

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \log(\alpha \lambda_i+1) + \frac{\alpha \lambda_i}{\alpha \lambda_i + 1} \right) .$$

Its derivative, a rational function, is easy to write down, and is manifestly positive-valued for all $\alpha$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant maximizing it.

Comment: Doesn't the objective function blow up when $\alpha \to \infty$? Is there even a maximum?

Comment: Good catch, @RodrigodeAzevedo !